# Authorize to google calendar without redirecting to log-in page

Tags: java, calendar, authorization, google-calendar-api, redirect

I would like to get instance of Google Calendar, but without redirecting to Google log-in page for user authorization. I am able to load client secrets like client ID, client secret etc. However, authorize() method is always redirecting me to google log-in page.

Is there any solution how to get credentials and authorization required for getting calendar and event instances from google, but just with authorization included in java class, not by redirecting to log-in page?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to go to the login page once, after that, you just need to call the refresh token process if the token is not valid.

Take a look here: https://developers.google.com/calendar/auth

Or, you can take a look in the [Google Service Accounts](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount)

> The Google OAuth 2.0 system supports server-to-server interactions such as those between a web application and a Google service. For this scenario you need a service account, which is an account that belongs to your application instead of to an individual end user. Your application calls Google APIs on behalf of the service account, so users aren't directly involved. This scenario is sometimes called "two-legged OAuth," or "2LO." (The related term "three-legged OAuth" refers to scenarios in which your application calls Google APIs on behalf of end users, and in which user consent is sometimes required.) Typically, an application uses a service account when the application uses Google APIs to work with its own data rather than a user's data.

Comment: Thanks, solution with Google Service Accounts finally works for my code.